# Array.filter() removing all elements from array... sometimes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is driving me insane. The desired outcome is for the `newArray` to return all but the element where the two `id`s match - this is outlined in code. When I add objects to the array and then try to remove them one by one, if the order is exactly reversed, the elements come out one at a time. If I choose an item that was added first, it removes them all.

Sample object in array - `id` is unique and an int:

```js
let newgeom = {
  id: geom.properties.ogc_fid,
  geom: geom
}
```

Code to remove is thus - maybe there is a better way but the intention was to see if the element was there by the `id` and then remove.

```js
let newgeom = {
  id: geom.properties.ogc_fid,
  geom: geom
}

let filteredArray = reportGeoJSON.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.id === newgeom.id;
});

if(filteredArray.length > 0) {
  console.log('removing poly')
  let newArray = reportGeoJSON.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id !== newgeom.id;
  });
  setReportGeoJSON(newArray)
} else {
  setReportGeoJSON(oldArray => {
    return [...oldArray, newgeom]
  })
}
```

Comment: return obj.id !== newgeom.id;, very probably this condition becomes true coz of string, int equality match, can you confirm?

Comment: Surely if an existing match is found you just shouldn't do *anything*; i.e. don't add the new object to the array. And your current deletion is simply finding all existing records that have an ID not equal to the new one, and using that as the new array, so it's no surprise you're losing the entries in it.

Answer (score 0):

Following what I think is your intended logic:

- check if the object already exists in the array, if so remove it.
- if it doesn't exist, add it.

which can be achieved using the following:

- call [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) looking for an object with a matching `id`. This will return an `index` if a match is found otherwise -1, if a match was found remove it using [`splice(index, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
- else, if `findIndex()` returned -1 (here checked by using the [bitwise NOT `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) to coerce -1 to 0 which is nullish), [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the new object.

```js
const
  reportGeoJSON = [{ id: 1, geom: 'geom1' }, { id: 2, geom: 'geom2' }, { id: 3, geom: 'geom3' }],
  setReportGeoJSON = (arr) => console.log(arr);

function addNewGeom(newGeom) {
  const
    newArr = [...reportGeoJSON],
    matchIndex = reportGeoJSON.findIndex(o => o.id === newGeom.id);

  if (~matchIndex) {
    newArr.splice(matchIndex, 1);
  } else {
    newArr.push({ ...newGeom })
  }
  setReportGeoJSON(newArr);
};

addNewGeom({ id: 3, geom: 'geom' });
//[ { id: 1, geom: 'geom1' }, { id: 2, geom: 'geom2' } ]

addNewGeom({ id: 5, geom: 'geom' })
// [{ id: 1, geom: 'geom1' }, { id: 2, geom: 'geom2' }, { id: 3, geom: 'geom3' }, { id: 5, geom: 'geom' }]
```